# jQuery sortable table not posting correctly on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I made a sortable table using jQuery, see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRbl2ey9gt4

I need it to post the positions of the items in the new order.

currently its posting empty values, see below:

```
Started POST "/episodes/sort" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-17 16:30:44 -0400
Processing by EpisodesController#sort as */*
  Parameters: {"episodes"=>["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]}
```

I know I have to use content_tag for, but I am not understanding the logic behind it, given that I am using a html table.

Here is my view:

#### Administer Episodes

```
<tbody id='eps'>
<tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Season</th>
  <th>Download?</th>
  <th>Shared?</th>
  <th>Length</th>
  <th>Status</th>
        <th></th>
</tr>
<% for episode in @episodes %>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%"><%=h episode.title %></td>
    <td><%=h episode.number %></td>
    <td><%=h episode.season %></td>
    <td><%=h episode.is_downloadable %></td>
    <td><%=h episode.shared_with_dev %></td>
    <td><%=h episode.length %></td>
    <td>
```

Excluding the unnecessary stuff.

Here's my JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#eps").sortable({

      // Maintains width when being sorted
      helper: function(e, tr){
        var $originals = tr.children();
        var $helper = tr.clone();
        $helper.children().each(function(index){
          $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width()) 
        });
        return $helper;
      },

      axis: 'y',
      placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
      cursor: 'move',
      dropOnempty: false,
      scroll: true,
      opacity: 0.4,
      tolerance: 'pointer',
      revert: 'true',

      update: function(event, ui){
        var itm_arr = $("#eps").sortable('toArray');
        var pobj = {episodes: itm_arr};
        $.post("/episodes/sort", pobj);
      }

    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `tr`s to have an attribute for jQuery UI sortable's `toArray` to fetch.
[The documentation indicates `id` is used by default](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray).

Try with

```
<tr id="<%= episode.id %>">
```